# how to give condition in merge field email template salesforce

Tags: formula, email-template, merge-field

on case object have one formula field called 'Team Name (API Name : Team_Name__c)'
having formula : `TEXT(Owner:User.CC_Team_Name__c )`
`CC_Team_Name__c` is a picklist field on user record

Email template currently displaying  `{!Case.Team_Name__c}`
How to make the value of `{!Case.Team_Name__c}` empty , if `Team_Name__c` is Bronze/Home or Gold/Silver ?

Comment: Hi Anjana, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. You don't need to let us know your question is about Salesforce. This question is on the *Salesforce* Stack Exchange. Please try to stick to relevant tags only.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read the formulas [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=0).

You can check the value of the picklist using an `IF` condition. You can also use an `OR` operator in this `IF`. Like this:

```
IF(OR(TEXT(Owner:User.CC_Team_Name__c ) = 'Bronze/Home', TEXT(Owner:User.CC_Team_Name__c ) = 'Gold/Silver'), '', TEXT(Owner:User.CC_Team_Name__c ))
```